# MongoDB: aggregation. Don't know how to use it correctly

Tags: python, mongodb

I need help with some project. 
Maybe somebody could help me.
I got some data in mongodb.
Now it looks like:

```
{
    Order: {
        order_id: id,
        SKU: some_vale,
        date: "10.10.1010",
        time: "12:12",
        product_name: some_name,
        number_of_goodies: some_value
    }
}
```

And I need to group it to look like:

```
{
    Order: {
        order_id: id,
        product:
            {
            SKU: some_vale,
            product_name: some_name,
            number_of_goodies: some_value
            }

        date: "10.10.1010",
        time: "12:12"

    }
}
```

Now there can be more than one document for one order. They got same order_ID but different products.
I was trying to use aggregation, but wasn't really successful.
If someone know how to solve this problem using aggrigation?

Answer (score 0):

```
coll.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': {'Order ID':'$Order.Order ID', 'date': '$Order.date', 'time': '$Order.time'}, 'products:': {'$push': {'SKU': '$Order.SKU', 'Number of goodies': '$Order.Number Of Goodies'}}}}])
```

Here is the solution if anyone is interested.
But please, comment, if you know a better way.